# How to use the maven ant task from gradle?

Tags: groovy, maven, gradle

I am trying to publish some artifacts to the maven central repo and since the current version of gradle (0.9-rc2) does not handle pgp I thought I would give it a try by 'porting' the ant xml [version](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide) while waiting for gradle 1.0 which hopefully will support it out of the box.

I wrote the following in gradle:

```
def mvn = 
    groovy.xml.NamespaceBuilder.newInstance(ant, 'antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant')

  mvn.mvn {
    arg(value: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.1:sign-and-deploy-file')
    arg(value: '-Durl=file:///tmp/repo2')
    arg(value: '-DrepositoryId=sonatype-nexus-staging')
    arg(value: '-DpomFile=pom.xml')
    arg(value: '-Dfile=myjar.jar')
    arg(value: '-Dfile=-Pgpg')
  }
```

Unfortunately it is not working and I am getting this:

```
Cause: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant:mvn
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
```

I have tried various combinations including adding the following at the top of my script:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.1'
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks
Yan

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know that Jörn Huxhorn has started the work of creating a plugin to allow for deploys to Sonatypes OSS Repo. The latest release is rough and requires the latest gradle sources to run but will do the job. More about the plugin here: http://gradle.codehaus.org/Plugins#Plugins-PGPPlugin

Comment: Thank you it is really good to know that it is coming!

Answer (score 7):

I did not find a way to use NamespaceBuilder but I found another way to be able to use the task directly which solves my issue:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    mavenAntTasks
}

dependencies {
    mavenAntTasks 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.1'
}

task hello << {
  ant.taskdef(resource: 'org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml',
              uri: 'antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant',
              classpath: configurations.mavenAntTasks.asPath)
  ant.mvn(...)
}
```